# Starting Jenkins bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, bash, jenkins, centos, centos6

I have a CentOS server and I'm trying to run jenkins as a service with:

```
service jenkins start
```

I am running as `root` user and I'm getting this response:

```
Starting Jenkins bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I have `echo`'ed a few things to the command line:

```
[root@xyz opt]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk
[root@xyz opt]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/opt/jdk/bin:/opt/grails/bin
[root@xyz opt]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
[root@xyz opt]# which java
/opt/jdk/bin/java
```

I cannot see any java configuration in any jenkins files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fix it by using:

```
ln -s /opt/jdk/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

The script file who service utility is using is probably /etc/init.d/jenkins
You could edit this file too...

Answer (score 6):

> Jenkins needs java to start and in your case in `/usr/bin/` directory `java` is not available

If you go to `/etc/init.d/` and open `jenkins` file you will find:

```
candidates="
/etc/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
"
```

These are the paths where jenkins looks for java, and in your case java was not present in any of the above paths.

So look for the path where you are having java and add that path in the above jenkins file.

Since you are having java in `/opt/jdk/bin`, then add this in `jenkins` file:

```
    candidates="
/opt/jdk/bin/java <----Add here 
/etc/alternatives/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
"
```